# Launch "Switch Between Windows" shortcut from keyboard?

Tags: windows-7

In Windows 7 there is a handy shortcut titled "Switch between windows", the actual filename is "Window Switcher.lnk". The shortcut brings up a view of my open windows where each window's content can be seen as if I was looking on at an angle and flipping through it like they were index cards (you do this using the mouse-wheel or arrows). Which is pretty cool, and I use it often when I have many windows open.

I'd like to be able to bring up this view using a hot-key, so I don't have to reach for the mouse: Hit a key combo, scroll through using arrows, , in some situations is going to be faster.

Is there a hot-key already for bringing that view up? Or is there a way I can bind a hot-key to a shortcut?

Comment: Some additional thoughts, if anyone is interested:
I had tried to simply set a hot-key on the short-cut itself, but it didn't appear to work. Just now, though I found a note on the web that led me to the conclusion that hot-keys on short-cuts don't work from the quick launch, the short-cut must be located on the start menu or desktop. So if you want to have a different hot-key, or perhaps bind it to your logitech mouse (which won't map to windows keys), put the shortcut on the menu, and set a customized hot-key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> and <kbd>Tab</kbd> :)

The official name is `Aero Flip 3D`, and it's been in Windows since Vista. To hold it there so you don't have to keep the Windows Key held down, hold <kbd>control</kbd> while you do it.

Comment: Oh. :). Was it dependent on Aero in Vista? Might be why I didn't have it then. :)

Comment: Hm. Windows-tab isn't quite the same as the short-cut, since it requires you to hold windows-tab down. Is there a way to change that behavior?

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while you press it, and you can release other keys.

Comment: Hm. I tried shift, and it didn't work, so I went ahead and tried control, on the off-chance you simply misremembered. That did the trick. So the correct combo for it to stick is ctrl-windows-tab. Thanks for the tips, Phoshi!

Comment: Whoops! I don't use it often myself, thanks for the heads-up.